# I want to change the cube color, which is created by three.js

Tags: colors, three.js, cube

I've created a cube like this

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh(
                     new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,20,50),              
                     new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x6699ff}) 
                );
                scene.add(cube);
                cube.position.set(80,32,40);
```

But I want to change the color of the cube, how could I do?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you use Ambient light check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717135/three-js-ambient-light-unexpected-effect). `cube.material.ambient = cube.material.color;` might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
    var color = 0x421575; // Your color
    cube.material.color.setHex( color );
```

The result is shown in those fiddles:

- For MeshBasicMaterial : http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/JLd6T/
- For MeshLambertMaterial : http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/dmTZg/1

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try this function, but it does't work. Someone says it is useful only when "MeshBasicMaterial". I don't know whether it is true. Do you have another function to save it? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you want to use a MeshLambertMaterial you have to correctly set the lights as well (this kind of material computes shadowing effects). The edited fiddle to the working MeshLambertMaterial is the following one: http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/dmTZg/1/  Hope this helps

Comment: Your function is available. I don't set the lights,I add  `renderer.clear(); renderer.render(scene, camera);.`                  It works. Thanks a lot. By the way, what's the difference between MeshBasicMaterial and MeshLambertMaterial. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: MeshBasicMaterial is used to draw flat or wireframed geometries,MeshLambertMaterial to draw non-shiny (Lambertian) surfaces. You can check the [THREE.js Documentation](http://threejs.org/docs) (even if not complete). If you want to see the differences on runtime, here you go : [link](http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/examples/webgl_materials.html)